# dojo mobile action on tab loads

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I made a simple mobile app (using Worklight Studio).
I add for this app the Dojo capabilities.
So, i have a TabBar and i want to have some action on clicking on tabs

MainPage.html (part of)

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar">
<li id="accountInfoButton" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/AccountInfoIcon.png" data-dojo-props="transition:'slide',dir:'1',url : 'views/account_info.html'">Account Info</li>
```

account_info.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRect" shadow="true">
<input id="name" dojoType="dojox.mobile.TextBox" selectOnClick="true" type=text name="name"></input>
</div>
<script src="../js/AccountInfoLoad.js"></script>
```

AccountInfoLoad.js

```
require("dojo/ready", function(ready){
    ready(function(){
        dojo.byId("name").innerHTML = 'John Doe';
    });
});
```

But nothing happens when i click on the Account Info tab

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: is the javascript on the target not executing? or is the fragment not being loaded at all.  Also check to javascript console to see if there is a dojo parse error.

Comment: javascript is not executed. i put a console.info and also an alert ... nothing happened.

Comment: @tinti, see my answer below. If my answer helped you, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, I believe this is not working for you because you are missing `moveTo:'<view id>'` in your `data-dojo-props`.
You need to specify the view to display in the page you are transitioning to.

The following works for me:

**index.html**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" fixed="bottom">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" id="tab1" data-dojo-props="url:'view1.html', moveTo:'view1', transition:'flip'">Label</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**view1.html**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view1" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
    In view 1   
</div>
```